# an Error with using ckfinder

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I use CkEditor and CKFinder in My C# Web Project.
but when I use ckfinder in my code ,I get an Error:

The type or namespace name 'ControlDesigner' does not exist in the namespace 
'System.Web.UI.Design' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and when I Add System.Design To my References ,this Error has been solved,but now I get
some Error such as this:

Duplicate 'AssemblyTitle' attribute

I need to use ckeditor & ckfinder and I use only Web project Not Web app,can any one help me?

thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one answer,this problem is because the C# web project has one AssemblyInfo in its properties. 
I Remove all of AssemblyInfo from CKFinder Folder,and Problem solved.

but I'm not sure that this way is right or wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Exclude all CkFinder assemblies from project, then you can run project. I tried and solved

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is by deleting the folders starting with '_' character from ckfinder folder ("_samples" and "_source"), because they are demo and developing folders. Those folders don't have any utility for you.